# Complexity of checking if a given prime number can be computed using at most $s$ addition/multiplication operations?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebraic-complexity, arithmetic-circuits, primes

Given are a prime number $p$ and a parameter $s\in\mathbb{N}$.

What is the computational complexity of the problem of determining whether $p$ is computable by a series of at most $s$ steps, each being either multiplication or addition? To be more specific, you can imagine this as an arithmetic circuit without variables, using only the constant $1$.

Notice how this problem is not really asking for the complexity of computing a prime number, but instead the question is about the smallest arithmetic circuit which outputs a specific $p$ from $1$. For example, you could imagine that those primes which have the value $2^{m}+1$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ are relatively easy to compute by adding to 2, then repeated multiplication, followed by +1.

One could also consider using the constant $-1$ as well.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you conjecture that prime numbers are an especially hard, or easy, case, compared to the same problem for general $n\in \mathbb N$? Did this question come from somewhere?

Comment: I would place high probability on (1) the problem for primes being as hard as the problem for general inputs and (2) the former fact being impossible to prove with current methods.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen My vague idea was that it could help me to solve small problems I have been trying to solve.
What Geoffrey Irving said would fit my idea about it, too.

Comment: It seem like there is an algorithm that runs in $O(\text{poly}(p))$ time.  (Note that you can get $p$ in $c \ln p$ steps (for some constant $c$) by building the powers of 2 in the binary representation of $p$ (using repeated squaring), then adding them.  So in the case that $s \ge c\ln p$ you are done (the answer is yes).  In the remaining case you can enumerate the circuits with $s$ nodes and try each.  I'd guess there are $\exp(O(s)) = O(\text{poly}(p))$ such circuits.)

Comment: @NealYoung Thanks for the comment. Yes, for these cases it is easy to see how they would work, but it would be more interesting to understand what primes are not "compressible" **at all**. Enumerating the remaining circuits won't have any benefits for the idea I was trying to follow.

Comment: Now, this problem is NP, but by solving that problem you can easily come up with the minimum $s$ required for any $p$ with binary search.

Comment: This is the Mahler-Popken complexity of the primes; see [A005245](https://oeis.org/A005245) for the complexity of n. The complexity of the primes doesn't seem to be in the OEIS (though [A075145](https://oeis.org/A075145) matches for many terms). There's a new upper bound on the complexity due to Zelinsky, though I doubt it would help you.

Comment: @NealYoung Yes, there's a trivial pseudo-polynomial algorithm (which can be improved slightly by the Zelinsky result I mention above, which comes, I believe, from using the base 55296 expansion rather than binary). But that just puts the problem in $E\cap NP$.